# checking if there are digits in a string

Tags: python, try-catch

How do I make that the for loop will actually check the whole *problems*, not just the first number in the *problems*?

```
def arithmetic_arranger(problems, display="False"):
    problems = "  ".join(problems)

    for i in problems:
      try:
          i = int(i)

      except:
          print('Error: Problems must only contain digits.')

    return problems
```

Comment: Don't `return` on the first match, collect the matches and `return` in the end

Answer (score 1):

Use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search). Convert each element of `problems` into string (for input to `search`). Search for regex that consists of 1 or more digits (`\d+`) that extend from the beginning of the string (`^`) to the end of the string (`$`).

```
import re
problems = [12, "2", 'three', "", None]

for problem in problems:
    if re.search(r'^\d+$', str(problem)):
        print(f'ok: {problem}')
    else:
        print(f'not ok: {problem}')
# ok: 12
# ok: 2
# not ok: three
# not ok: 
# not ok: None
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays make this easier. Do a int() on all elements of the list problems. Use map(). It takes two parameters: func, iterable. It applies func() on all elements of iterable, and returns a map object. Then convert it into a list.

```
def arithmetic_arranger(problems, display = "False")
    problems = list(map(int, problems))
    return "  ".join(problems)
```